# How to rescue "kill: Operation not permitted"?

Tags: ruby, process, ubuntu-12.04, kill

I want to rescue "Operation not permitted" when killing a process but I don`t know how!

```
def kill(process)
          process.each do |line|
            if line.include? "java"
              process_no = line.split[0]
              `kill -9 #{process_no}`
            end
          end

        end
        while true
          retry_count += 1
          # check if tomcat is alive!
          tomcat = `ps axf | grep tomcat`
          process = tomcat.split(/\n/)
          if checkPID(process)
            print "."
            if retry_count < 3
              print "."
            else
              puts " try to kill.."
              begin                      #=>=(((it doesn't work
                kill(process)
              rescue Exception => e
                puts("")
                break
              end                        #=> =((((

            end
```

I`m cheking it in the while loop but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to rescue from `SystemCallError`

```
rescue SystemCallError => e
```